# Can hive table be accessed by Impala and the other way?

Tags: hive, cloudera-cdh, impala

I am trying to access one of the table created by the hive using Impala . Is there any issue with such access . Also is it good to access a table created by Impala by Hive .

Answer (score 0):

If you create a table in Hive, you must issue `INVALIDATE METADATA` in Impala in order to see the new table.

If you create a table in Impala, you will be able to use it in Hive right away.

See the [INVALIDATE METADATA Statement](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_invalidate_metadata.html) and [How Impala Works with Hive](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_hadoop.html#intro_hive) for details.